# DEB and RPM packaging

Tags: deb, packaging, rpm

I have an application that I'd like to pack into DEB and RPM for making it installable into Linux distributions such as:

- Debian
- Ubuntu
- Linux Mint
- Fedora
- OpenSUSE

Do I need to develop an extra DEB file for Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint? Or does it suffice to create one for Debian that'll work for Ubuntu and Linux Mint, too?

What about RPM with Fedora and OpenSUSE?

Comment: It depends on the package and it's dependencies. Each distro can have a different set of dependencies and libs so you may need to package for each distro. Simple packages such a wallpapers probably not.

Comment: It would be a good idea to test your application installation on all of those distros plus different releases. Welcome to fragmentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried it, but it seems that [openSUSE build service](https://build.opensuse.org/) will help:

- [openSUSE:Build Service cross distribution howto](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_cross_distribution_howto)
- [openSUSE:Build Service Debian builds](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_Debian_builds)

Ubuntu has `obs-build` package in repositories [since Xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=obs-build).

Also you can try [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/) or [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/).